# Spring Boot Add a Custom TemplateAvailabilityProvider

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, templates, spring-boot

Our current project is setup with custom Template resolution where instead of using the templates directory we have setup the template resolver to first look under templates/domain/xxx, if template is not found it will them use templates/default/xxx

The above is all good and working, but we are now having trouble setting up the default error handling. By Spring Boot DefaultErrorViewResolver, it will first look at templates/error/[status-code].html before moving on to templates/error.html.

Unfortunately due to our template resolution setup, I can't place the templates in the above directories as it wont resolve. But if I place the templates under resolvable location under either template/domain or template/default the TemplateAvailabilityProvider is unable to detect it and hence always end up with the default error page.

I was able to create my own custom TemplateAvailabilityProvider which will perform the template look up in accordance with our template resolution

```
public class CustomMustacheTemplateAvailabilityProvider extends MustacheTemplateAvailabilityProvider {

    private TemplateFinder templateFinder;

    public CustomMustacheTemplateAvailabilityProvider(TemplateFinder templateFinder) {
        super();
        this.templateFinder = templateFinder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTemplateAvailable(String view, Environment environment,
                                   ClassLoader classLoader, ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        if (ClassUtils.isPresent("com.samskivert.mustache.Template", classLoader)) {
            PropertyResolver resolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment,
                "spring.mustache.");
            HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
            view = templateFinder.getTemplateName(request, view);

            String prefix = resolver.getProperty("prefix",
                MustacheProperties.DEFAULT_PREFIX);
            String suffix = resolver.getProperty("suffix",
                MustacheProperties.DEFAULT_SUFFIX);
            return resourceLoader.getResource(prefix + view + suffix).exists();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, because all the providers are loaded via SpringFactoriesLoader

```
public TemplateAvailabilityProviders(ClassLoader classLoader) {
    this.resolved = new ConcurrentHashMap(1024);
    this.cache = new LinkedHashMap(1024, 0.75F, true) {
        protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Entry<String, TemplateAvailabilityProvider> eldest) {
            if(this.size() > 1024) {
                TemplateAvailabilityProviders.this.resolved.remove(eldest.getKey());
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
    Assert.notNull(classLoader, "ClassLoader must not be null");
    this.providers = SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactories(TemplateAvailabilityProvider.class, classLoader);
}
```

I am unable to find a way to add my newly created TemplateAvailabilityProvider (I can add my own spring.factories in my project and hack my way it, but I am trying to avoid it if at all possible)

Any help is greatly appreciated